# Salesforce Closed/Won email

Tags: email, template, alert

I'd like to display account information, such as company registration number in the opportunity closed/won email but it doesn't pull through. What am I doing wrong:

```
Sales Won notification
Opportunity details:
Opportunity Number: {!Opportunity.Symity_Opportunity_number__c}
Opportunity Name/Topic: {!Opportunity.Name}
Full Revenue Amount: {!Opportunity.Amount}
More opportunity details here : {!Opportunity.Link}.
Client Details: 
Client Name: {!Opportunity.Account}
Client Number: {!Account.Company_registration_Number__c}
Account Manager: {!Opportunity.OwnerFullName} 
Client registration number: 
  {!Account.Company_registration_Number__c}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
Client Name: {!Opportunity.Account.Name}
Client Number: {!Opportunity.Account.Company_registration_Number__c}
Account Manager: {!Opportunity.Owner.FullName} 
Client registration number: 
  {!Opportunity.Account.Company_registration_Number__c}
```

Comment: thanks. Tried it after you suggested. Oddly, it seems to rewrite it to  {!Opportunity.Account} every time i run it

Comment: ah, right - I forgot about the [cross-object merge fields in email templates issue](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385133&type=1) (which is why I generally use VF emails when this is an issue in my legacy orgs)